# Resizing images efficiently

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, image-resizing

My dataset contains 102235 images which I stored in a list and saved as a pickle file. I would like to train a neural network with these images.

Therefore, I would like to resize the images.

I used the following code but my Jupyter Notebook died.

```
import pickle

images = pickle.load(open(r"path\to\pickle\data\*.pkl", "rb"))

import cv2
def resize_images(img, new_width, new_height):
    size = (new_width, new_height)
    resized_img = cv2.resize(img, size)
    return resized_img

import pandas as pd
images = images.tolist()
resized_img_train = [resize_images(img, new_width=224, new_height=224) for img in images]
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Edit: I do not want to use TensorFlow or Keras since my computer seems to have problems with these two packages.

Comment: There are better ways of doing this, at least in TF and probably also in Keras. If you're using Tensorflow you could look into this tutorial: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification

Comment: Are there also better methods without using Keras or TensorFlow?

Comment: there are many Python modules for Neural Networks (ie [PyTorch](https://pytorch.org/), [sklearn](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neural_networks_supervised.html), even cv2 has some [elements](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/ml/doc/neural_networks.html)) but Googles give access to servers with GPU and `TF` can use it. https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/intro.ipynb

Comment: I know Colab, but is it possible to upload such a huge file (3GB) there without crashing it? Unfortunately, TensorFlow and Keras are not working on my Jupyter Notebook at the moment...

Comment: did you try to use TensorFlow/Keras without Juputer ? If you get error then you could create new question with this error.

Comment: I didn't try this but Colab should works with Google Drive so you could keep images on Google Drive. Eventually maybe you could train it partially. And I would not keep images in pickle but as normal files - they should use less space.

Comment: Yes, I also tried TensorFlow with Spyder and got the same error message... Yes, you are right, the actual images are smaller than the pickle files... I will first try it in Colab before asking a new question. You think the best solution is to use a generator like the one (train_image_generator) mentioned on this site: https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/images/classification?